# Concurrency issue - Saxon 9.6 on .NET, XSLT and custom XmlResolver and CollectionUriResolvers

Tags: c#, xml, multithreading, xslt, saxon

I'd like to validate my understanding of Saxon's XSLT objects and concurrency.

Basically, I need custom resolvers to return request-specific data to transforms, and currently, I'm creating new instances of the resolvers for each transform for each request.  I've had early reports of data from one request used in another, which is a significant problem.

---

Using Saxon 9.6.0.6 HE on .NET 4.6 (C#), Windows 7/Server 2012.

My code can execute many different shared transforms for many concurrent requests.  Saxon's compiled XSLT is a must for performance.  Currently, the code is multithreaded (using TPL and async where appropriate), and does not use locking (and want to avoid this if possible).

I've had occasional reports of data being incorrectly 'leaked' across requests in the output of transforms (ie, likely a concurrency issue).  I'm not sure if this is linked to the behaviour of the custom XmlResolver or the custom  CollectionUriResolver.  I'm awaiting more information.  I haven't yet been able to recreate the issue (still working on this and will post updates if I can).

Our transforms use both fn:doc and fn:collection.

The code precompiles all possible transforms on application startup.  These executables are shared.

For a given transform in a transaction, my code creates an XsltTransformer object via the compiled executable's .Load() call.  This appears to create a new object looking at the 9.6 HE code (which is what I'd expect).

Next, my code creates new instances of a custom XmlResolver and CollectionUriResolver (haven't yet moved to CollectionFinder but think this may operate in the same manner) and these are populated with the appropriate request-specific docs/values/etc to feed into the transform.

These two resolvers have a lifetime of just one XSLT execution - they're not reused.

We associate the resolvers with the XsltTransform objects the only way I know how:

```
Saxon.Api.XsltTransformer transform = executable.Load();
transform.InitialContextNode = sourceData; 
transform.Implementation.getConfiguration().
    setCollectionURIResolver(collectionResolver);
transform.InputXmlResolver = inputResolver;
```

In the Saxon code, it *looks like* the input resolver is instance based and therefore not shared (ultimately appears to live in the Controller class as shown below, which itself is a new instance when the XsltTransformer is created via Load()).

```
public XmlResolver InputXmlResolver
{
    set
    {
        controller.setURIResolver(new DotNetURIResolver(value));
    }
}
```

However, I'm worried that the configuration data may be shared, and in setting the collection resolver on the configuration object (the CollectionFinder appears to be the same) we may have our concurrency problem.

What is the right way do achieve the outcome I'm after - for our custom resolvers to respond with request-specific behaviour?  Can I use one pair of instances per transform with request specific data in, or do the resolvers have to be shared across requests (possibly injecting the request ID into the transform to form part of the URIs passed to the resolvers)?

**Slight update**
It appears you can set the CollectionURIResolver on both the controller ('Implementation') directly, or on configuration, and these are distinctly different objects in memory:

```
transform.Implementation.setCollectionURIResolver(collectionResolverOne);        
transform.Implementation.getConfiguration().
    setCollectionURIResolver(collectionResolverTwo);
```

However, at runtime, it's the configuration's resolver that is invoked (collectionResolverTwo in the case above).  I'm not sure what purpose the controller's copy serves.

Additionally, it would appear that the configuration data is indeed shared, because if I create a 2nd transformer from the same executable and set it's collection resolver at configuration level, this updates the resolver used by the 1st transformer.

So - I think I've found my problem - I just now need to know the right thing to do in my scenario where I need the collection resolver to resolve the collections uniquely for each request (eg, one request might have five entries in a particular collection, another might have two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in explaining your problem you have essentially solved it yourself. The Configuration object in Saxon (which underpins the Processor at the API level) is shared, and after any initialization it's strongly recommended not to change its state using methods such as setURIResolver(), since such changes will affect work-in-progress in an undefined way.

Saxon has API objects and internal objects with a one-to-one correspondence, and the internal objects aren't 100% encapsulated because some users need access to more intimate functionality. In the Java world there are also JAXP classes that are conceptually similar, but restricted to XSLT 1.0 functionality. The correspondence is:

*Shared information about the Saxon environment as a whole:*

**API**: Processor  **Internal**: Configuration  **JAXP**: TransformerFactory

*Reusable XSLT compiler containing options for compiling stylesheets:*

**API**: XsltCompiler  **Internal**: CompilerInfo  **JAXP**: no equivalent

*A compiled stylesheet, which can be executed repeatedly (and concurrently in multiple threads)*

**API**: XsltExecutable  **Internal**: Executable/PreparedStylesheet  **JAXP**: Templates

*A single transformation, transforming one source document using one stylesheet:*

**API**: XsltTransformer  **Internal**: Controller  **JAXP**: Transformer

Some configuration options in Saxon are available only at the Configuration level, for example, the set of collation URIs available is defined at this level, and cannot be varied from one transformation to another.

However, URIResolvers can generally be defined at the XsltTransformer/Controller level. They can also be set on the Processor/Configuration, but that's just a default if you want to use the same one throughout. In your situation you should be setting them at the Controller level.

Comment: Thanks!  I think the problem I'm facing here is due to 9.6.0.6 not working as expected.  Upgrading to 9.8.0.2 solves the problem - the resolvers are not shared, as expected.

Comment: However - there is one piece of unexpected behaviour.  When I set both a custom URIResolver and CollectionURIResolver on the Controller, calls to fn:doc use the custom URIResolver as expected, *but*, any URIs resolved by the custom CollectionURIResolver are loaded by the URIResolver associated with the Configuration object, not the Controller.  You can see this in the CollectionURIResolverWrapper code.

Comment: I've updated to using the CollectionFinder interface.  Seems to do the trick.

Comment: Does the CollectionURIResolverWrapper need the option to have a URIResolver supplied to it rather than acquiring it from configuration?  At any rate, I'm pretty sure CollectionFinder is the way to go for me, so problem solved!